# Unable to push or pull images to/from private docker registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

I have recently migrated my application from one AWS account to another account during which I have changed the docker registry URL from docker.app.prod.aws.abc.com to docker-hd.app.prod.aws.abc.com.

We have GitLab application hosted on AWS.
The runners/instances which are on AWS are able to push or pull images from the new docker registry without any issues. But the runners which are on-prem are getting error as "Forbidden".

Can someone please help me to fix this issue..

I have updated the DNS records for new docker registry but still getting forbidden error.

It was working fine before the migration.

Comment: Do the runners have the required IAM permissions?

Comment: how is the access/credentials configured for the runners that are on-prem?